# Keep on getting "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, cors

I am working on a Task Manager proyect, making the front end with react, and the back end with Springboot.

When trying to make the login (calling the POST "http://localhost:8080/api/user/login"), but I keep on getting the same message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/user/login' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have tried both the @CrossOrigin annotation and making a `WebMvcConfigurer` bean, but nothing.
I am completely stuck in all honesty.

This is the CorsConfig In question

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5173")
                        .allowedMethods("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .exposedHeaders("*")
                        .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is how I am making the request from the front end:

```
const signin = async (user) => {
    try {
      console.log("User to be logged in: ");
      console.log(user);
      const res = await loginRequest(user);
      setUser(res.data);
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
    } catch (error) { 
      console.log(error);
      setErrors(() => [error.response.data]);
    }
  };
```

The login request in question:

```
export const loginRequest = (user) => axios.post("/user/login", user);
```

And lastly this is the user controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> loginUser(@RequestBody User user) throws UserNotFoundException, WrongPasswordException {
        userService.loginUser(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("The user has logged in");
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@RequestBody User user) throws InvalidUserNameException {
        userService.registerUser(user);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("The user has successfully been created");
    }
}
```

I have already tried things like @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") and @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:5173"), and all sort of things like, specifying the allowed methods, headers, etc. Idk what to do anymore, perhaps I did something wrong that I am not seeing.

Thanks in advance for the help, I'm super stuck and have been searching for an answer for like 3 hours now, and nothing.

Comment: Did you look at the network tab? What exactly does your server return?

Comment: In your UserController, the /login endpoint is a @GetMapping, but from your React front-end, you're making a POST request.

Comment: @Feelfree It appears that that was indeed the problem JAJAJA. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was making a POST request to the server, when It should have been a GET request. Rookie mistake.

Thanks @Feelfree for pointing it out!